# Fontspec + Cabin + LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I want to use the [`Cabin` fonts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cabin/) (which are available on CTAN).  It seems possible to use these fonts with `LuaLaTeX`, since there are `type1` fonts available, and on CTAN it says:

> LuaLaTeX and xeLaTeX users who might prefer type1 fonts or who wish to
>   avoid fontspec may use the type1 option.

However, I'm using [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), so now I'm confused.

How can I get these fonts to work with `LuaLaTex` + `fontespec` ?

Comment: `cabin.sty` has code to make the switch automatically, so just do `\usepackage{fontspec}\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}` (or remove `[sfdefault]` if you don't want `cabin` to be your main document font).

Comment: @jon and how do I set it for just a small footer? (My main font is actually `georgia` set by `\setmainfont{georgia}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a special footer font, I suppose you'd want to use `fontspec` directly.  I'm not sure what your actual document looks like, but you could use `fancyhdr` in this case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{georgia}
\newfontfamily\footerfont{Cabin}% default: Cabin-Regular

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\footerfont just a small footer}
\fancyfoot[RO,RE]{this is not in Cabin}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

This is not the footer and it's not in Cabin.

\end{document}
```